# Copy files from a WWW folder to External Server through SCP

Tags: linux, bash, apache, ssh, scp

I want to copy some local file allocated in a local web-server (under `apache-2`) to a external server folder.
I already copied the public key in the external server and my password is not required when I access via `Linux Terminal`, but when I try to do the same using a `Bash` script, the command doesn't work, and nothing happens.
Here my `sh` code:

```
#!/bin/bash

text=("$1");
times_text=("$2");
gender=("$3");
pitch=("$4");
mood=("$5");

paste <(printf "%s\n" "${times_text[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${text[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${gender[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${pitch[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${mood[@]}") > ./tmp/data.txt

cat ./tmp/data.txt  | cut -f 2-2 | while read line; 
do 
    echo $line >> ./tmp/file_to_copy.txt;
done

scp ./tmp/file_to_copy.txt user@externalServer:Folder/to/copy
```

I need to do these commands remotely and I don't know why the file is not copied in the desired external server folder.

Comment: No, because this script is executed through a PHP script

Comment: trace php error log or catch the exception .. do one thing try this manually on server to shift data from `server a ` to `server b`

Comment: Ok! this is the message: 
Host key verification failed.

lost connection

Comment: ok.. do you have access of both servers?

Comment: Yes, I have access through my user and IP address of the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove know khost from you ssh for both servers.

Follow below steps.

- Go to below directory

> cd /root/.ssh/

- Edit `known_hosts` file with `vim` command and delete alll data from this file using `dd` commnad and save the `known_hosts` file with `:wq!`

Do the above steps for both srever remote and local.

Comment: I did this, but I got the same error as before... I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Host key verification failed. lost connection

Comment: try to ssh your server `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@host`